# How to join the result of two tables to get desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **LeftTable** and **RightTable** with the respective data.

**LeftTable**

```
loginid                                            position   level
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- -----------
9972                                               L          1
9973                                               L          1
9974                                               L          2
9975                                               L          2
9976                                               L          2
```

**RightTable**

```
loginid                                            position   level
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- -----------
9977                                               R          1
9978                                               R          1
9979                                               R          2
```

I tried following query

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN LT.loginid > RT.loginid THEN LT.loginid 
    ELSE RT.loginid 
  END LoginID,
  LT.level
FROM #LeftTable LT 
INNER JOIN #RightTable RT ON LT.level = RT.level
```

and got result

```
LoginID                                            level
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
9977                                               1
9977                                               1
9978                                               1
9978                                               1
9979                                               2
9979                                               2
9979                                               2
```

But I want result like this.

```
loginid                       level
---------------------------- -----------
9977                              1
9978                              1
9979                              2
```

**Note**- Here Loginid is MAX not from the RightTable

The result is based on each record in right table is also present in left table based on **level**  i.e if three records are present in **lefttable** but in **righttable** there is only record on level 2 then it should return only one record or vice versa. LoginId will be the greater one.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add. It is hierarchical data. I have used recursive CTE.

Comment: looks like you want `DISTINCT`?

Comment: That query isn't an rCTE though. Do we not have the full picture here?

Comment: @Larnu. Thanks. How can I forget distinct. I am getting result now but I will have to test in real scenario. For now its working.

Comment: @Larnu sad, it didn't work. If in one record login id in righttable is greater from lefttable it works fine but if in second record login id in lefttableis greater from righttable I get duplicate records

Comment: Please restate the rules.  For a given LEVEL, do x?

Comment: Like I said, I suspect we don't have all the details here. You reference an rCTE above, but there's nothing about that I. Your question.

Comment: What should happen for 9981, L, 3 where level is only in Left table?  What should happen for 9982, R, 4 where level is only in Right table? What should happen when level is present is each table-- select only all of the Right rows for that level?  ("LoginId will be the highest one" seems to be a spurious/misleading statement because it has no effect on the desired output)(OR-- there is not enuf sample data to properly test the sql).

Comment: Hi all, thanks for helping me out. I found that this is not possible with query. So I had compared the each record in the leftTable with rightTable based on Level. If it matches then I saved in third temporary table. Then delete the top row with each iteration.

Comment: @Larnu The data in LeftTable and RightTable is using RCTE. I don't think it was required here. I was answering the question in which you were asking Where does the level come from?